# Pass Int[] in HTTP Get to CoreWebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor WebAssembly Hosted project and am in need of posting up an Array of Ids to get.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet("GetByTypePaged/{ingredientTypeIds}/{startIndex}/{count}/{search?}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetByTypePaged([FromQuery]int[] ingredientTypeIds, int startIndex, int count, string? search)
```

However the ingredientTypeIds comes back as int[0] so no Ids are being retrieved.   Ive tried FromRoute and i get a 415 as well as without FromQuery

FromUri does not exist within the name spaces

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
```

Id have to install the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core nuget package to get the System.Web.Http namespace.  However, then the

```
[Authorize]
[Route]
[HttpGet]
```

etc all have ambiguity between the System.Web.Http and AspNetCore.   If I remove the references to the Microsoft.AspNetCore then I loose the [FromBody] for my HttpPut operation.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Update(int id, [FromBody] Ingredient ingredient)
```

Whats my best approach here

Answer (score 0):

> [HttpGet("GetByTypePaged/{ingredientTypeIds}/{startIndex}/{count}/{search?}")]

In your code we can find you defined a route with route parameters `ingredientTypeIds`, `startIndex`, `count` and optional one `search`.

Please note that [route data and query string values are used only for simple types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0#sources), if you'd like to pass an array of Ids in URL and bind to action parameter `int[] ingredientTypeIds`, you can modify your route and [pass it through query string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0#collections) in this format:

```
ingredientTypeIds[0]=1&ingredientTypeIds[1]=2
```

Besides, if you'd like to pass complex-type data to your backend API, you can make your endpoint support the HTTP POST method, and you can pass the expected data through request body.